# How do I run C++ Programs on Windows Command Line using MinGW

Tags: c++, cmd, mingw

I am following the following tutorial:

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/mingw_for_first_time_users_howto

Everything works fine until i get to the portion of the tutorial where the instructions read: Type filename.exe into the prompt and your c++ program will run.

When I type this in I get the following message:

""The procedure entry pont __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll.""

How do I fix this problem?

My specs are:
Windows 7 (64 bit)
Using MinGW

Comment: if you are using dll's codes, you should put them on the same folder as the executable, or on the path.

Comment: If it's not because your compiler is broken, then you can probably solve it by adding -static flag. Then, your compilation command will look like g++ helloworld.cpp foo.cpp -o helloworld.exe -static. (Another option is to copy libstdc++-6.dll and libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll from mingw/bin to your application folder. But the first option is more simple.)

Comment: A follow up question. If i put the dll's codes, as well as the g++ compiler, can anyone with windows then run the c++ code? just curios.

Comment: Where are you going to find dll's code? I don't fully understand what you mean. Anyway, if you're going to distribute your program, you have two options. First: you can do what I've described above (use `-static` or place dll's in a same folder with exe). You don't need to distribute cpp files in this case. Others wont need g++ to run the program. Second option: This is for cases when you want to give your program to another programmer and you want him to be able to modify/examine it. You just give cpp files, that's all. Then receiver must compile the code himself.